# why OrderBy is not working in my query Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use orderBy in my query, but its not working , $price contain 'asc' and 'desc' value after submitting form, but same value is showing in my blade. After click price (high to low) I want to show Product with high to low prices. Thanks Advance

[image: values coming from blade]

```
    return Listing_property::latest()
        ->when($city, function ($query, $city) {
            return $query->where('city', '=', $city);
        })
        ->when($type, function ($query, $type) {
            return $query->where('property_type', '=', $type);
        })
        ->when($purpose, function ($query, $purpose) {
            return $query->where('purpose_type', '=', $purpose);
        })
        ->when($bedroom, function ($query, $bedroom) {
            return $query->where('bed_room', '=', $bedroom);
        })
        ->when($bathroom, function ($query, $bathroom) {
            return $query->where('bathroom', '=', $bathroom);
        })
        ->when($minprice, function ($query, $minprice) {
            return $query->where('price', '>=', $minprice);
        })
        ->when($maxprice, function ($query, $maxprice) {
            return $query->where('price', '<=', $maxprice);
        })
        ->when($property_size, function ($query, $property_size) {
            return $query->where('property_size', '>=', $property_size);
        })
        ->when($property_area_type, function ($query, $property_area_type) {
            return $query->where('property_area_type', '<=', $property_area_type);
        })
        ->when($price, function ($query, $price) {
            return $query->orderBy('price',$price);
        })
        ->where('add_type', $types)
        ->paginate(3);

}
```

Comment: try `toSql` function to check whether you're getting input data proper and your query is right.

Comment: one more thing, you are using `latest` at the top that would also create an issue.

Comment: yes without orderby query is working perfectly

Comment: `->where('is_published ', '=', '1')` should be outside

Comment: I didn't get your point... I am still stuck

Answer (score 1):

because you are using  Listing_property::latest() ...

and  latest() make this:

```
$query->orderBy('created', 'desc')
```

now your query would have in its generated sql:

```
 order by `created_at` desc, `price` asc
```

to order by price first, you simply add it to your query builder before 'latest()':

```
 return Listing_property::when($city, function ($query, $city) {
       // ....
->when($price, function ($query, $price) {
            return $query->orderBy('price',$price);
        })
       ->where('add_type', $types)->latest()->paginate(3);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. 
still not properly working , but values are changing when I click buttons